# Regex issue in Angular with password pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, validation

Having some problem with **FormControl()** **Validators.pattern()** with this regex expression for validate password with 1 char, 1 digit, min 8 chars, max 16 chars.

---

Tested passwords that pass the validators:

*asdfqwer* //that should not pass the validator

*zxcvasdf* //that should not pass the validator

*asdfqwer2* //that's correct

---

Tested password that do not pass the validators:

*programm* //that's correct

---

Trying this pattern in server-side or using online regex test platforms there are no problems

```
// some code
password: new FormControl('',
    [
      Validators.minLength(8),
      Validators.maxLength(16),
      Validators.pattern('^$|^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,16}$')
    ]),
// some code
```

Comment: why you have `^$` at start ? `^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,16}$` this is enough you don't need to check length also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Validators.pattern('(?:(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])(?=\\D*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{8,16})?')
```

Angular will enclose the string pattern with `^` and `$` automatically, making it `'^(?:(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])(?=\\D*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{8,16})?$'`.

Note the double backslashes: in a string literal, you must escape a backslash with another backslash to define a literal backslash, which is a regex escape char.

Since the whole pattern is enclosed with an optional non-capturing group, an empty string will also be matched with the pattern.

The `(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])` and `(?=\\D*\\d)` now have no `.*` which is in line with the [principle of contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast).